How to Wrap FlatList rendered Items in a Fixed-Height Container in React Native?
I have a problem where I want to render a list of items using FlatList, but I expect a large number of items and want to wrap these items in a container with a fixed height. This is to save screen space, and I also want this container to be scrollable.
Here is the code I have so far:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Modal,
} from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const newOrder = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Item 1",
      description: "Description 1",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Item 2",
      description: "Description 2",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Item 3",
      description: "Description 3",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Item 4",
      description: "Description 4",
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      name: "Item 5",
      description: "Description 5",
    },
  ]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ padding: 4, paddingLeft: 0, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'gray' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18 }}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text style={{ color: 'gray' }}>{item.description}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderHeader = () => (
      // Here I have components like text, text inputs etc....
  );

  const renderFooter = () => (
    // Here I have other components...
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 16 }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18 }}>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem} // I'm talking about can this render be wrapped in other scrollable component with fixed height?
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
          ListHeaderComponentStyle={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default newOrder;

I've tried to put in the main FlatList empty data array and to render the items in another FlatList component inside of the header and the footer parts of the main FlatList. I've also tried to make the data, which the FlatList receive, to be wrapped in one main arr, so that the FlatList can think that there is only one element, and inside of the const renderItem = ({ item }) => (); to render another FlatList/ScrollView with the actual elements, but both the things I tried didn't work for me as I expected and also this things seems to me pretty wrong to do.
I want to wrap the items rendered by the FlatList in a container with a fixed height that can also scroll. This is to manage the screen space better as I expect to render many items.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
